# Imported Brushes stop working, but stock brushes still work fine

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I have imported a series of brushes that I have been using for a project.  I am familiar with the tools and use them regularly.  I know and understand a basic troubleshooting process if a brush is not affecting the mesh (edit then scuplt mode, mesh resolution, masks, etc.)

The brushes import fine, and work normally most of the time, but then stop working for some reason, sometimes upon start of the file.  What was working fine, just suddenly stops, and then will start working again, for reasons i dont undrstand / cant seem to figure out.  When this is happening, the stock brushes in blender seem to work fine.

Also, and perhaps unrelated, when I import them, it will not import all of them, and the image will show as a blank, gray square.

Could someone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: workaround / update: If I append the file again, it will start working, although i then have duplicates of each brush set, and one set doesnt work.